# ¿Cómo encuentro el número mágico 0xCAFEBABE?

Tags: java

He oido que las clases de Java tienen algo llamado un número mágico en las cabeceras que las identifica, y que dice algo así como `0xCAFEBABE`.

> ¿Alguien podría explicarme cómo puedo comprobar dicha información?

Comment: te debes referir a 0xCAFEBABE no "cafe babe" :)

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarlo?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "comprobar dicha información"?

Comment: A que no lo creo

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Si simplemente necesitas convencerte, quizás Wikipedia te pueda ayudar: (en inglés) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#Magic_Number

Comment: Necesito verlo, no convencerme

Comment: ¿Te refieres al identificador único de clase que es usado para el hashCode o es cuando ves el nombre de la clase + la dirección en memoria?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bueno respecto a tu pregunta, cuando abres un archivo .class con un editor hexadecimal, se puede observar "cafe babe" si es que este contiene este número mágico.

De hecho [aquí](http://www.javamexico.org/blogs/srcid/magic_number_0xcafebabe) encontré una explicación del propio **[James Gosling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling)**

> Soliamos ir a almorzar a un sitio llamado St Michael´s Alley. De
>   acuerdo a una leyenda local, en el profundo y oscuro pasado, el grupo
>   Grateful Dead solia tocar ahí, antes de que se hicieran famosos. Era
>   un lugar bastante moderno que hacia honor al nombre de la banda (un
>   lugar digno para morir). Cuando Jerry el lider de la banda murió
>   colocaron un pequeño altar budista. Cuando íbamos ahi soliamos llamar
>   al lugar "Cafe Dead". Alguién noto que era un número hexadecimal. Yo
>   reimprovisaba el código del formato del archivo de clase y necesitaba
>   unos numeros mágicos: uno para el archivo de objeto persistente y otro
>   para las clases. Yo utilice CAFEDEAD para el archivo de objeto
>   persistente, y buscando un patron en los primeros 4 digitos "CAFE", y
>   una variante en los demás me vino a la mente BABE y lo use. En ese
>   momento no parecia demasiado importante o destinado a ir a cualquier
>   lado como al bote de basura de la historia. Así que CAFEBABE llego a
>   ser el formato de archivo de clase y CAFEDEAD el formato de archivo de
>   objeto persistente, pero con el tiempo el objeto persistente se fue
>   junto con el uso de CAFEDEAD que fueron reamplazados por RMI."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los primeros 4 bytes son "el número mágico",

- 0xCAFEBABE,

para identificar un archivo de clase válido.

Los próximos 2 bytes *minor version number* identifican la versión del .class que se utiliza.

Los los próximos 2 bytes *major version number*

- J2SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),
- J2SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
- J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
- J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
- JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
- JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
- JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
- JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de editor hexadecimal para probar tu respuesta por favor?

Comment: En internet puedes encontrar bastantes, sin embargo mi favorito es notepad++ en realidad es un editor de texto pero soporta modo Hexadecimal =)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/

Answer (score 3):

El número mágico está presente al inicio de todos los archivos .class como resultado del proceso de compilación del código fuente. Con un editor de texto sencillo como Notepad en Windows es posible observar esto, o con cualquier editor de texto hexadecimal, como Notepad++, también abriendo los archivos con un editor común presente en sistemas operativos GNU/Linux omo gedit, nano o vi.

Comment: Al abrir con notepad me sale Êþº¾   2 ?

Comment: Creo que debes leerlo en hexadecimal

Comment: Exacto lo que comenta Joel, debe ser un editor hexadecimal o si lo soporta cambiarlo a modo hexadecimal.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Hay un plugin para Notepad++ que permite abrir como editor hexadecimal: Solo despliega el menú "Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager". En la ventana emergente selecciona la pestaña "Available" y marca **HEX-Editor**. Haz clic en el botón "Install" para descargarlo. Una vez instalado aparecerá en la barra de herramientas con un ícono de "H"

Comment: Un excelente editó de hexadecimal es hexedit, gratis y ligero, por acá les dejó el sitio http://www.hexedit.com/