# ¿Por qué mi array toma basura una vez lleno? (lenguaje C)

Tags: array, c

El objetivo del algoritmo es para comprobar si un fichero es autentico (sin modificar su contenido) mediante la comparación de sus primeros 4 caracteres.

Tengo un fichero cuya primera linea contiene "*RIFFÆà˜WAVEfmt* " y por ende, los primeros 4 caracteres son "*RIFF*". Mi problema es que al llenar un array de longitud 4 sólo con letras '*A*' (para realizar pruebas) e imprimirlo, este arroja basura que además ocupa espacio extra del que definí anteriormente en el array y, en consecuencia, lo mismo sucede al llenar el array con *RIFF*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printer(char array[], char letras[]){

  if (strcmp(array,letras)==0)
      printf("\n\ncorrecto");

  else
      printf("\n\nincorrecto");

  getch();
}



int main(){

  FILE *archivo=fopen("fichero.txt","r");

  char array[4];

  printf("\n\n%s\n\n",array); //se imprime el array sin llenar

  getch();

  for (int i=0;i<4;i++){ //se llena el array con AAAA
      array[i]='A';
  }

  printf("\n\n%s\n\n",array); 

  printer(array,"AAAA");

  for (int i=0;i<4;i++){ //se llena el array con RIFF
      array[i]=fgetc(archivo);
  }

  printf("\n\n%s\n\n",array);

  if (strcmp(array,"RIFF")==0)
      printf("\n\ncorrecto");

  else
      printf("\n\nincorrecto");

  return 0;
}
```

Aplicando el código, en consola este es mi resultado:

```
ð↓@



AAAAh£¿u



incorrecto

RIFFh£¿u♦



incorrecto
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal para que el array esté tomando basura?

PD: Uso Codeblocks para Windows

Comment: ¿Tu archivo es un audio? ¿O es un archivo de texto?

Comment: Originalmente un audio

Comment: Los audios son archivos binarios y tu lo estás tratando de leer como texto, te recomiendo revisar esta pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272/c%C3%B3mo-encuentro-el-n%C3%BAmero-m%C3%A1gico-0xcafebabe/275#275

Answer (score 3):

C no tiene el concepto de *cadenas*; como ya sabes, solo tiene *formaciones* de caracteres y punteros a carácter.

Entonces, si no tiene *cadenas* ... ¿ como sabemos, en el lenguaje C, cuando es **el final** de una formación de caracteres ?

El lenguaje utiliza una marca especial, el carácter `\0x00` (0) como *finalizador*. **Todas** las funciones que trabajan con cadenas tienen como mínimo 1 versión que espera justo eso, una cadena **terminada en `0`**. Además, muchas de ellas soportan trabajar con cadenas de tamaño fijo: aquellas que pueden o no estar finalizadas por un `0`, pero no es necesario, puesto que conocemos el tamaño exacto de caracteres que la forman.

Ese es el problema de tu código:

```
char array[4];
```

Declaras una formación de **exactamente 4** elementos, y luego la *rellenas* con **exactamente 4** datos ... ¿ y el fin de cadena ?

Una posible solución es hacer

```
char array[5];
```

para recordar siempre que tenemos que poner nosotros un `0` al final:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
  array[i] = 'A';
}
array[4] = 0;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, no sabía eso del 0 como delimitador en una cadena. Y efectivamente, siempre habrá 'algo' en una cadena, me expresé mal al querer decir 'asignar'.

Comment: @Esteban No siempre es necesario poner un `0` al final, hay funciones que trabajan con cadenas de tamaño fijo: `printf( "%.4s\n", array )`, `strncmp( array, "RIFF", 4 )`, ... pero es un detalle *curioso* del lenguaje que lo distingue de otros, y es importante el saberlo :-)